# The memory cost of a hash_map structure in C++ STL

Tags: c++, hash, stl, unordered-map

In order to use hash_map, I assume that a consecutive memory block will be allocated, but what's the size of this block by default?

Comment: It is probably implementation specific.

Comment: @TonyD Would you please add your answer below so that I can accept that as a correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following is for `unordered_map` - the name for the hash map in C++11 onwards...

While the initial size is implementation specific, the default [`.max_load_factor()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/max_load_factor/) is stipulated by the Standard to be `1.0`, so in general the number of buckets will only automatically increase when `.size()` becomes greater. Gives you a bit of a feel for things....

You can also call [`.bucket_count()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/bucket_count/) to get the instantaneous count.

Answer (score 0):

The size of each block will depend on the implementation .

e.g. your hash map declaration is : hash_map homier;

Then the each hash block size will be = (bucket size of the string ) + (bucket size of the integer) as per the OS architecture.